# $(a_n)$ is covergent. $(k_n)\in\mathbb{N}$, $(k_n)\to\infty$. Decide if $(a_{k_n})$ is covergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series

$(a_n)$ is covergent sequence. $(k_n)$ is natural sequence such that $(k_n)\to+\infty$.  Is it true that $(a_{k_n})$ is covergent ?

Being honestly, I have no idea how to solve this problem. Can you help me ?

Comment: This looks like a homework problem, can you write down what you have tried so far? What are your thoughts about this?

Comment: @Happy man: Using the definition of "$(k_n)\to +\infty$" and the definition of "$(a_n)$ is convergent" should not be that difficult. Can you write them down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix $\varepsilon>0$. By the convergence of $a_n$, $\exists N$ such that for all $n>N$, $|a_n-l|<\varepsilon$.

Now, since $n_k \rightarrow \infty$, $\exists K$ such that for all $k>K$, $n_k>N$.

Thus, for all $k>K$, $n_k>N$ so $|a_{n_k} - l|< \varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it converge !

Let $\varepsilon>0$. By definition of the convergence of $(a_n)$ (we denote $\ell$ it's limit), there is $N\in\mathbb N$ s.t. $$|a_k-\ell|<\varepsilon$$
when $k\geq N$. Since $n_k\geq k$, when $k\geq N$, you also have $n_k\geq N$, and thus $$|a_{n_k}-\ell|<\varepsilon$$ when $k\geq N$. The claim is proved !

Comment: I think you need to be careful here. The question wasn't asking about subsequences of a_n but any n_k tending to infinity.

Comment: What would be $(a_{n_k})$ if it's not a subsequence of $(a_n)$ ? Anyway, even if $n_k$ is not increasing or not injective (what would be weird...), the proof is very easely adaptable since by definition of $k_n$, there is a $M$ s.t. $k_n\geq N$ for all $n\geq M$. @Chessanator

Comment: Sorry: I wasn't clear. The definition of subsequence requires that n_k be increasing. Thus you do have to throw in that adaptation to get the required proof.

Comment: The notation $a_{n_k}$ is never used when $(a_{n_k})$ is not a subsequence of $(a_n)$. @Chessanator